# Ansible-playbook: how to write content of var to file

Tags: ansible

I have a var, i want to write content of var to a line in file.

Example:
var: TEXT_NEED_TO_ADD

file before added:
some_line
text text mark text text
some_line

file after added:
some_line
text text mark TEXT_NEED_TO_ADD text text
some_line

What should i do?
Sorry for My English.

Comment: This question needs some improvement, it's not really a question, you've not told us what language you would like to achieve this in, it needs a lot more information before someone could provide you with a constructive answer.

Comment: create an ansible module using python. There you can write your own logic to manipulate the file and then call that module from you ansible playbook. Let me know if you need further help in this.

Comment: Use Ansible lineinfile module

Answer (score 2):

If your file is static(by which i mean that you want to insert the TEXT_NEED_TO_ADD just once during deploy) the best way (and easiest to maintain) to go about is creating a jinja2 template file and using it in your role.

So your file structure should be:

```
your_role/
  templates/
    my_file_template.j2
  tasks/
    main.yml
```

and your files should look like this:

main.yml

```
- name: copy file and fill it
    template: src=my_file_template.j2 dest="/home/user/my_file"
```

my_file_template.j2

```
some_line
text text mark {{TEXT_NEED_TO_ADD}} text text
some_line
```

this way ansible will insert the contents of the variable into a file(in a place of {{TEXT_NEED_TO_ADD}}) before copying it into location specified by dest. You can use as many variables in jinja template as you wish. Ansible also supports many filters and other usefull tools (such as loops for example). But i guess using `sed` would be fine too. Depends on what you want to achieve.
you can read more about template module [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html)
and you can read more about templates [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/container_yml/template.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do some magic with `sed` command:

```
- name: insert string in file
  shell: sed '/mark/a {{ TEXT_NEED_TO_ADD }}' filename
```

I'm not really good in sed manipulation, but the general idea is: if you can't do it with Ansible, try to do it in Bash and if you could - setup Ansible to do it for you. 
Or you can write Ansible Module to do it, but often Bash is really enough.